# Why has methods are not generated using protoc 3.17.* if in protobuf repo they say it should?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto, protoc

Reading here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/field_presence.md#go-example the Golang example:

```golang
m := GetProto()
if (m.HasFoo()) {
  // Clear the field:
  m.Foo = nil
} else {
  // Field is not present, so set it.
  m.Foo = proto.Int32(1);
}
```

if I use:

```
protoc pkg/user.proto --go_out=. --go_opt=module=my_app --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=module=my_app
```

with:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

package example;

message MyPlayer {
  uint64 id = 1;
  optional string description = 2;
  uint32 qty = 3;
  optional uint64 age = 4;
}
```

it doesn't generate any `has<T>()` method.

Why?

```golang
// Code generated by protoc-gen-go. DO NOT EDIT.
// versions:
//  protoc-gen-go v1.26.0
//  protoc        v3.17.3
```

Am I wrong if I use `MyPlayer` generated proto fields instead of methods?

Example:

```golang
if MyPlayer.description != nil {
  description = *MyPlayer.description
}
```

instead of

```golang
description = MyPlayer.GetDescription()
```

which is not what I want (I want to detect nil values).

Comment: From the docs: To enable presence tracking for proto3 messages, pass the --experimental_allow_proto3_optional flag to protoc.

Comment: @BurakSerdar, this is not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That docs is wrong, as reported here: https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1336:

> The documentation on https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/field_presence.md#go-example is incorrect. Using "optional" in proto3 makes the field be generated just as it would in proto2.

> That doc is wrong. There are no `Has` methods in the generated code. Test for presence by comparing fields to `nil`.
>
> Rewriting those examples correctly:
>
> ```
> // Field foo does not have presence.
> // If field foo is not 0, set it to 0.
> // If field foo is 0, set it to 1.
> m := GetProto()
> if m.Foo != 0 {
>   // "Clear" the field:
>   m.Foo = 0
> } else {
>   // Default value: field may not have been present.
>   m.Foo = 1
> }
> ```
>
> ```
> // Field foo has presence.
> // If foo is set, clear it.
> // If foo is not set, set it to 1.
> m := GetProto()
> if m.Foo != nil {
>   // Clear the field:
>   m.Foo = nil
> } else {
>   // Field is not present, so set it.
>   m.Foo = proto.Int32(1)
> }
> ```

> PR to fix that doc:
> [protocolbuffers/protobuf#8788](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/pull/8788)